# How to add a user to PostgreSQL in Windows?

Tags: database, postgresql, configuration

I'm running PostgreSQL on mt Windows 7 machine.  To run a database I type:

```
C:\psql -Upostgres mydb
```

and this works, but it would be nice if I could leave off the `-U` stuff, but then Postgres thinks I'm trying to log in as 'Eric', since that is my user profile.

So I need to add a user to Postgres, obviously.  But how?  If I try:

```
C:\createuser Eric
```

Postgres thinks I'm trying to add a user Eric *as the user Eric* which fails.  Adding the `-U` flag doesn't seem to work here.

What am I missing?  My command window is in administrator mode, and there is no `sudo` available, obviously.

Comment: Looking back six years later, I would probably not attempt this. Installing Postgres on dev machines is a pain, just use the standard Postgres/Docker image: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In pgadmin you can create a new "Login Role" and name it Eric and give it permissions graphically, or from command line you can do something like this

```
psql -U postgres -c "CREATE ROLE Eric LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE;" mydb
```

see http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/sql-createrole.html for information on the CREATE ROLE options.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much. I looked everywhere but this is the only clear , concise, and working answer I've found ;-)

Comment: Is there any difference between login role and ordinary user like postgres ?

Answer (score 4):

Just to add more information. From [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-createuser.html): you can specify the user under which createuser utility logs in to postgres via environment variable:

```
PGUSER
```

One liner for powershell:

```
& { $env:PGUSER="postgres"; .\createuser.exe Eric}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for `createuser`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-createuser.html) indicates that a `-U` switch is accepted:

> `-U username`
>   `--username username`
>
> > User name to connect as (not the user name to create).

This is what I would expect to use (although I've never tried to set up PostgreSQL on Windows, only on unices).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me `--username Shweta;`

Now to create a database `create database db;`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest case is to use the Windows command line and as I understand that the user `posgres` is present:

```
psql -U postgres -c "CREATE ROLE shpp;"

psql -U postgres -c "ALTER ROLE  shpp WITH LOGIN;"

psql -U postgres -c "ALTER USER  shpp CREATEDB;"

psql -U postgres -c "ALTER USER  shpp WITH PASSWORD 'shpp';"
```

In my `shpp` example, this is the name and password of the new user.