# Heroku not letting me push my database to my app (did not find magic string in file header)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I have been developing a ruby on rails application for one of my classes. Recently I converted my sqlite database to postgres so that I could push it to Heroku and host my app from there.

I run,

```
heroku pg:push development_pg HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN --app myapp
```

and after I enter my password i get this stack with an error at the end and it aborts the push.

```
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: reading user-defined functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined types
pg_dump: reading procedural languages
pg_dump: reading user-defined aggregate functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined operators
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator classes
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator families
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search parsers
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search templates
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search dictionaries
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search configurations
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign-data wrappers
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign servers
pg_dump: reading default privileges
pg_dump: reading user-defined collations
pg_dump: reading user-defined conversions
pg_dump: reading type casts
pg_dump: reading table inheritance information
pg_dump: reading event triggers
pg_dump: finding extension members
pg_dump: finding inheritance relationships
pg_dump: reading column info for interesting tables
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "answers"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "answers"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "categories"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "categories"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "challenges"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "challenges"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "games"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "games"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "player_stats"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "player_stats"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "questions"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "questions"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "schema_migrations"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "scores"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "scores"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "users"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "users"
pg_dump: flagging inherited columns in subtables
pg_dump: reading indexes
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "answers"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "categories"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "challenges"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "games"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "player_stats"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "questions"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "schema_migrations"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "scores"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "users"
pg_dump: reading constraints
pg_dump: reading triggers
pg_dump: reading rewrite rules
pg_dump: reading large objects
pg_dump: reading dependency data
pg_dump: saving encoding = UTF8
pg_dump: saving standard_conforming_strings = on
pg_dump: saving database definition
pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header
pg_dump: [custom archiver] could not write to output file: Invalid argument
```

I'm using Windows 8. Can someone help me or explain what is going on please?

Comment: This could be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26046916/429758