# "pg_dump: [custom archiver] could not write to output file: Invalid argument" while building ruby apps (window OS, gitbash)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi all im building ruby on rails apps on window using gitbash.

i have this error message

```
pg_dump: server version: 10.1; pg_dump version: 9.6.6
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

after running code:

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL mylocaldb --app myapps
```

current searched solution are for Ubuntu or Mac OS, is there any advise to fix this for window?

im hitting a roadblock on this.
thanks.

****ISSUE ON TOP FIXED****

after reading all the tables, i was greeted with the following error message in Gitbash.

```
pg_dump: saving encoding = UTF8
pg_dump: saving standard_conforming_strings = on
pg_dump: saving database definition
pg_dump: [custom archiver] could not write to output file: Invalid argument
```

anyone knows why?
i am unable to find any solution online.

thanks.

Comment: AFAIK (and I'm not an expert) there's a big difference between v10 and v9.6 - can you up/down-grade your local db to match the version on the server? (always a good idea to have the same version), then try? There will probably be tutorials on this for windows (sorry, I'm not familiar enough to find one).

Comment: hi i fixed that, but a new issue arise. updated in the main post

Comment: oh sure. generally speaking it's better to ask a new question as a new question on Stack overflow... it puts it at the top of the queue again, and the answers/commentary don't all get tangled up together. There's no problem with copying it out and asking a new one :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku pg:pull failing to populate schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870388/heroku-pgpull-failing-to-populate-schema)