# I'm having trouble with password field while using pg:pull with my Heroku postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am using the `Cloud9 IDE` which has an `ubuntu` operating system. I recently uninstalled my local SQLlite3 database from my Rails app and successfully installed a local postgres database. I am now trying to pull the postgres production database from Heroku.

If I run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_get(:@config)`in Rails Console:

> {:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :pool=>5, :template=>"template0", :username=>"ubuntu", :password=>"password", :database=>"learning_app_development"}

From the command line per [these](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-pull) instructions:

```
$ heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL mylocaldb --app my-app-6503
```

> heroku-cli: Pulling postgresql-meadows-7463 ---> mylocaldb 
>   Password:

After I enter password in this field, it fails:

> createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "ubuntu"

[This answer by Elliot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545746/cloud9-postgres) is the instructions I followed to setup postgres locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with this answer:

[heroku pg:pull password authentication failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220225/heroku-pgpull-password-authentication-failed)

from Joel.

It does not make any sense to me all besides that maybe Heroku will not accept password as the password?