# Role "username" not found: PostgreSQL Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql

I found the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189026/how-to-add-a-user-to-postgresql-in-windows) among many other solutions for **nix* systems, but I couldn't seem to access `psql`

> Simply throws a **fatal error** telling that **role *Username* doesn't exist** while I have just created the role and can explicitly see that role there in the list

[image]

Things were going super smooth with `sqlite` and now I need to migrate all data from `sqlite3` to `PostgreSQL` and I'm stuck here for hours...! **What do I do?**

Comment: psql version `9.6.1` on windows `10` in case that matters

Comment: Could it be case sensitivity? The role name "zeke" in postgresql is not the same as "Zeke" - because you gave the command without quoting the name it's all lower case... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796446/postgres-case-sensitivity#21798517

Comment: it is indeed! such a silly thing...!

Comment: is there a way to make `postgres` take _username_ instead of _Username_ as default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Solution 1:** Use *doublequotes* to preserve case: `psql -U postgres -c "CREATE ROLE \"Zeke\""`

In `Windows` usernames are usually given as `Username` but psql command refuses to preserve **case**! and this is causing the error...

> **Solution 2:** `psql -U zeke`

<strike>I still wonder if there exists any solution for taking usernames in windows as **lowercase** characters!</strike>  Adding an ENV variable `PGUSER` helps get rid of `-U zeke` after every `psql` cmd

Comment: `PGUSER` [Environment Variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) or `create role "Zeke" ...` Also look at the [User Name Maps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-username-maps.html)

Comment: You missed doublequotes around the role name in my comment.

Comment: yep! it works: `psql -U postgres -c "CREATE ROLE \"Zeke\""`