# Rails Postgres db:migrate no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails

it was answered many times but I am too dumb and need someone to explain me like Im 5 years old.

I get:

```
C:\Users\Jaiel\Desktop\Uebung_3_Elias_Kechter_s0555064_SoSe_2018_AI_Web_Entwicklung\order_management>rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Im on Windows. Have a Rails 5 App, which works like a charm using sqlite3 as databse. But unfortnuately Heroku doesnt want me to have a worrking app and demands postgresql.

I dont know where to put my password.

This is my database.yml:

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.1 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: order_management_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  #username: order_management

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: order_management_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: order_management_production
  username: order_management
  password: <%= ENV['ORDER_MANAGEMENT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I just want it to work for 2 hours now I have been reading and still dont understand what I am doing wrong.

I have tried to paste "password: pass" (my password) under the `development` section

but still get:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Passwort-Authentification failed for user Jaiel
```

Comment: if i understand well, you had your dbs configuration with sqlite then you changed for pg ? you want all your environments running with pg or just production ?

Comment: nope I made a new one with the ``--database:postgresql`` option

Comment: Add username and password to development environment and create same user in postgre https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189026/how-to-add-a-user-to-postgresql-in-windows. Then create database `rake db:create` Also make sure your pg gem is in your gemfile for all environments (but I think it is there already)

Comment: yeah I resolved it you are right. There was no role called ``Jaiel`` shakingmyhead

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you want to run your application in Heroku, and it will running with production mode. So Rails will get database infomations from database.yml and the `production` seciton.

In which, your setting for the database is:

`production:
  <<: *default
  database: order_management_production
  username: order_management
  password: <%= ENV['ORDER_MANAGEMENT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>`

it says that the password will get from the server environment with the name `ORDER_MANAGEMENT_DATABASE_PASSWORD`.

If you don't know how to set that and your application is not a real product, you can replace `<%= ENV['ORDER_MANAGEMENT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>` with the real password like `abc123`.

---

update 1.

Also, I have noticed that you put `adapter: postgresql` setting in default section, and your development section is inherented from the default section, so the database adapter for you development database setting is `postgresql` but `sqlite`.

You should fix the problem or you will get database error in your localhost development.

And for more and greater explaining, you can read [Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Rails 5)](https://www.railstutorial.org/).

---

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: no I am far away from running it on heroku. I am trying to run it locally in development environment. I provide my password but it just wont let me `Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"order_management_development", "password"=>"5"}`

Comment: I changed password in pgadmin to 5 and did `password: 5` under `develoment` section it still fails authentification

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer. I updated the answer. Create and use database in localhost, the default choice is sqlite, but you set your adapter to `postgresql` for all the environments. So change it to `sqlite` or add a line in development section.

Comment: Please read the book and write codes with the book, maybe you need to know more basics.

Comment: what do you eman with "Also, I have noticed that you put adapter: postgresql setting in default section, and your development section is inherented from the default section, so the database adapter for you development database setting is postgresql but sqlite."

Comment: I mean you set your default database adapter to postgresql with 'adapter: postgresql', this will let your application use postgresql as database in your localhost development, but you use sqlite instead. So add a line `adapter: sqlite3` in your developement section of database.yml file.